# jQuery allow contextmenu only on certain elements

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

```
// this works

$(document).on('contextmenu', function() {
    return false;
});
```

```
// without the code above, this works too

$(document).on('contextmenu', '#special', function() {
    alert('#special right clicked');
});
```

How can I combine these 2 pieces of code so that I can disable context menu on the whole document except the one with id #special.

Comment: your second code should disable all others, except the id#special....

Comment: no, the second code does nothing but alert for #special. if the first code is presented, it overwites the second.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("#special"))
       return false;

    alert('#special right clicked');
    // you may want e.preventDefault() here
});
```

Using the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) lets you test whether the clicked element matches any selector, which is basically what your original delegated `.on()` call did behind the scenes, but if you're checking for an element id specifically it would be more efficient to say:

```
if (e.target.id != "special")
    return false;
```

Comment: aha...that easy...I was expecting some contextmenu plugins answers. thanks. (5 more minutes to accept answer)

Comment: @user1643156 - I hope you realize that some browsers (Chrome/Firefox) have settings that don't allow you to block the right click menu with javascript so this won't universally work in all browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the heads up. I just tested on Chrome 23 and Firefox 3.6 & 15, they all work so far.

Comment: There's a setting in FF for context menus under Options / Content / Advanced JavaScript Options.