# How to add an exception to a jQuery that disables right-click?

Tags: jquery, binding, return, preventdefault, right-click

I am trying to disable right-click in the whole page except for two elements that are meant to be copied. I know disabling right-click sounds like a bad idea about every time, but it makes sense to me in this case. I found some information about how to unbind elements to re-enable a behaviour that was prevented using preventDefault(); and also tried with return: true for the exceptions, but it wasn't successful. There's no trigger for re-enabling the right-click feature, it should be all at once.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

I also tried this:

```
var disablerightclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();      
}
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).bind('contextmenu', disablerightclick);   
});
//]]>
```

It works everytime. But it doesn't let me unbind anything else directly below and it makes sense it doesn't, I will try something and update whether it works or not.

This is the update I mentioned previously. It doesn't work...

```
var disablerightclick = function(e) {
    return false;    
}
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').mousedown(function(){return false});
        $('body').bind('contextmenu', disablerightclick);
    });
    $('#AnyObject').hover(function() {
        $('body').unbind('contextmenu', disablerightclick);
    });
```

I will keep trying since I am not getting any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696810/jquery-allow-contextmenu-only-on-certain-elements)

Use this code:

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("#special"))
       return false;

    alert('#special right clicked');
    // you may want e.preventDefault() here
});
```